# How to shar video and audio using xmpp?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

i made chat app.i shared video and audio using following code but it take too much time.so any one have solution for this then please give me.

For Audio :-

```
NSData *dataAudio = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

dataAudio=[dataAudio gzippedData];

NSString *audioStr=[dataAudio base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];

[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"ANY_ID_NAME"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[[self xmppStream] 
 myJID].full];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:dictionary[@"to"]];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"chattype" stringValue:@"singlechat"];

 NSXMLElement *data=[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"data"];
[data addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" 
 stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"];
[data addAttributeWithName:@"seq" stringValue:@"0"];
[data addAttributeWithName:@"sid" stringValue:@"Stream0002"];

[data setStringValue:audioStr];

 NSXMLElement *xmlmediatype=[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"mediatype"];
[xmlmediatype setStringValue:@"audio"];

[message addChild:xmlmediatype];
[message addChild:data];


 [[self xmppStream] sendElement:message];
```

For Video :-

```
videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videourl];
NSString *videoStr=[videoData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];

[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"ANY_ID_NAME"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[[self xmppStream] 
 myJID].full];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:dictionary[@"to"]];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"chattype" stringValue:@"singlechat"];

NSXMLElement *data=[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"data"];
[data addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" 
stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"];
[data addAttributeWithName:@"seq" stringValue:@"0"];
[data addAttributeWithName:@"sid" stringValue:@"Stream0002"];

[data setStringValue:videoStr];

NSXMLElement *xmlmediatype=[NSXMLElement 
elementWithName:@"mediatype"];
[xmlmediatype setStringValue:@"video"];

[message addChild:xmlmediatype];
[message addChild:data];


[[self xmppStream] sendElement:message];
```

using above code video and audio shar is working but it take too much time for share.some times it giving error time out.

so any one have solution or code related to this then please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Sharing video and audio quicker should be easy. Just upload it to your server and share a format(with downloadable link). Which will tell receiver to download the file at his end. Now the speed will totally be dependent on speed on which your server operates.

Comment: thank you rptwsthi . i will try your solution and any other solution using xmpp then please giving me.I make app like whats app.